# Passing XElement to Webservice .The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request WebService

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I was working on webservice.I want to pass XmlDocument to method in webservice.But read on one of the article to pass XElement instead. I am calling web service from windows form , but it throws exception

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(FilePath);

        MyClient client = new MyClient();
        XElement element = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(doc));

        client.PassXml(element);//Exception at this line

        client.Close();
```

My webservice

Interface

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        string PassXml(XElement doc);
```

Class which extends interface

```
 public class Service: IService
    {
    public string PassXml(XElement doc)
    {
        //My Logic
        return "Done";
    }
}
```

I tried following way but cant get it worked

```
 [DataContract]
       public class XmlDoc
        {
           [DataMember]
           public XmlElement doc { get; set; }

        }
```

then assigning my Xelement to doc

```
XmlDoc xml = new XmlDoc();
  xml.doc =element;
```

and passing it to method throws same exception.

```
 client.PassXml(element);//Exception
```

Any Solutions

My Xml

```
<Main>
<Product SKU="101091">
    <Name>Anchor White Tooth Paste 200Gm</Name>
    <Mrp>54.0000</Mrp>
    <Price>53.2800</Price>
    <Cost>46.0463</Cost>
    <Barcode>101091,8904000900457,8904000900501,8904000900624,8904000900631,9910109100017,9910109100727</Barcode>
  </Product>
  <Product SKU="101094">
    <Name>Haldiram's Khari Bundi 40Gm</Name>
    <Mrp>10.0000</Mrp>
    <Price>9.1287</Price>
    <Cost>0.0000</Cost>
    <Barcode>101094,9910109400018,9910109400124,9910109401206</Barcode>
  </Product>
</Main>
```

app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INopService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:64223/Service.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INopService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.INopService" name="BasicHttpBinding_INopService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: If your webservice already uses SOAP you don't need to be adding another layer of XML serialization on the top of it. Why not consider using strongly typed models?

Comment: thanks but i am new to WCF is there any workaround to this

Comment: The whole point is that in a WCF webservice you should design the service to take a data contract (a class). And then have the client pass an instance of this class to the service. WCF will take care of the underlying serialization so that you don't need to be dealing with any `XElement`.

Comment: can you provide some reference link to know more about topic u stated?

Comment: Any *WCF getting started tutorial* will provide you with an example.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov thanx i tried ur way to go, but it throws same exception. Please check update

Comment: Can you post the XML you're trying to pass to the service?

Comment: A couple other things: `XmlDoc xml = new XmlDoc(); xml.doc =xml;` makes no sense.  You create an instance of the `XmlDoc` and then assign that instance to itself - but unless there's code you didn't show, you have nothing in that instance.  Secondly, the idea of a `DataContract` is to take the data that you were intending to pass as XML and send it as an instance of the object, not to send XML wrapped in a data contract.  So, for example, if you had XML that had first and last name, the Data Contract would have properties for first and last name.  WCF would then serialize it.

Comment: updated that was by mistake xml.doc=element

Comment: @NitinVarpe - Can you post an example of the XML you're trying to pass?

Comment: posted my xml please check @Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up Darin's comments regarding using a data contract, here's an example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Product
{

    [DataMember]
    public string SKU { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal MRP { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    List<string> Barcodes { get; set; }
}
```

You could then change your operation signature to:

```
string PassXml(List<Product> products);
```

However, it appears that the data you want to pass is already in XML, so another option would be to do this:

```
string PassXml(string xml);
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(FilePath);

try
{
    MyClient client = new MyClient();
    client.PassXml(doc.ToString());
    client.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    client.Abort();
    // do something about the error
}
```

Then in your service implementation you could use `XDocument.Parse()` to turn the string back into an `XDocument` and do whatever processing you need.

Note also that if you're sending a lot of data, you might be exceeding the some of the limits of the service (which could also generate a 400 error).   Try either of the above suggestions and if you still get a 400 error, post your service's config file.

**ADDED**

You run a risk with the second approach in exceeding maximum string content length (the default is 8192).  I would increase the settings in your binding for `maxReceivedMessageSize`, `maxBufferSize` (these two must be equal) as well as `maxStringContentLength` to a larger value.  I would suggest using 2147483647 to start for all three.

Comment: so i need to parse xelement and add one by one object to list in my application, right

Comment: To use a Data Contract, yes.  That's why I suggested an alternative approach - simply call `ToString()` on the `XDocument`, and then pass the string in, and convert it back to an `XDocument` in the service implementation by using `XDocument.Parse` on the string.

Comment: Depends on how large and what your service settings are.  Post your service config file and I can edit my answer to handle large string sizes.

Comment: See my edit for a suggestion on how to handle large strings.  These changes go in your service config (similar changes would need to be made in your client if your client will be receiving large amounts of data back from the service).

Comment: thank you very much for ur unconditional support will use and run my app

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your element in a  tag and pass it

```
postData = @"<string xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'><![CDATA[" + your XMLelement + "]]></string>";
```

Basically `<![CDATA[""]]>` stop the serializer to treat it as XML.